# How do I make a Jupylet app working inside of an if statement in a Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am using a Jupylet app inside of my notebook. If I run `app.run()` inside of a cell it works fine, but if I trigger the run from an if statement as in my example code, it does nothing. There are no errors, but the app does not show up. How can I solve this?

```py
    import sys
    import os
    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('./..'))
    from jupylet.label import Label
    from jupylet.app import App
    
    app = App(width=320, height=64)
    hello = Label('hello, world', color='cyan', font_size=32, x=app.width, y=22)
    
    @app.run_me_every(1/24)
    def scroll(ct, dt):
        hello.x -= dt * 48
        if hello.right < 0:
            hello.x = app.width
            
    @app.event
    def render(ct, dt):
        app.window.clear()
        hello.draw() 
    
    c = 3
    if c == 3:
        app.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

In [Jupylet](https://github.com/nir/jupylet#jupylet), app.run() returns a [Jupyter ipywidgets.Image](https://github.com/nir/jupylet/blob/master/jupylet/app.py#L339) object. it is that object that gets displayed when you run the cell.

You can access it with app.canvas after the call to app.run() and if you evaluate it in a cell the game canvas should be displayed. For example:

```
In []: app.canvas
Out[]: ...game canvas should display here...
```